# Catch error when created custome expect in jest

Tags: jestjs

I created testing Helper Functions as Globals in Jest to be able to use them throughout our application in every single one of our test files.

I am going to cut this out of our testing file. I am going to go to setup-global.js file, and then I will say global.loopExpect = `expect() // for looping case`

```
global.loopExpect = (actuals) => {
  return {
    toContainKeys: (keys) => {
      if (actuals.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < actuals.length && i < 5; i++){
          expect(actuals[i]).toContainKeys(keys)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

get_array.test.js

```
test('check contains Book property', async () => {
  loopExpect([{title: 'SOLID Principles', author: 'Uncle Bob Martin'}])
    .toContainKeys(['year'])
})
```

And when the test is run, I should get an error because the actuals object does not containr object's `year` property, right .

But I get an error report on my terminal, and showing the error from at Object.toContainKeys in the file `setup-global.js`. Even though I want  the error message on the failed test to appear at Object.toContainKeys in in the test file `get_array.test.js`.

How to the test file catch the error or `global.loopExpect()` function throwing error so JEST thinks the error coming from the test file ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think you need `loopExpect`, because there is a simpler and more durable way to implement this:

```js
test('check contains Book property', async () =>
    [{title: 'SOLID Principles', author: 'Uncle Bob Martin'}].forEach(book => 
        expect(book).toContainKeys(['year'])
    )
)
```

But if you really want a helper function and you need to know where the test failed, one way to know is to look at the stack trace. And if you want the error to have a different stack trace, with the line from your test file on top, then you can wrap your test in a `try` block, and throw a new error from the `catch` block.

Comment: yes you are right it makes more sense.

And thank you for the description of the errors.